# Access json field's dict value which is inside list using queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have django model named Blog with fields title, data

```py
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    data = models.JSONField(default=dict)
```

I have about ten of instances with data field value like

```
Instance 1
[
    {
        "name": "random"
    }
]
Instance 2
[
    {
        "name": "fact"
    }
]
Instance 3
[
    {
        "name": "fact"
    }
]
Instance 1
[
    {
        "name": "random"
    }
]
Instance 1
[
    {
        "name": "random"
    }
]
```

And I am trying to sort the the blogs based on data field name key is used, and show it like

```
random, 3
fact, 2
```

and I am intending it to do it more efficiently with database functions.

```
top_used_names = Blog.objects.annotate(
    name=RawSQL("REGEXP_REPLACE("data", '^.\*\\"name\\": \\"(.\*?)\\".\*$', '\\\\1')", params=\[\])
).values('name').annotate(
    count=Count('name')
).order_by('-count')\[:5\]
```

but It showed me errors.

then I tried using

```
top_used_names = Blog.objects.annotate(
    name=Cast(KeyTextTransform("name", "data"), output_field=TextField())
).values("name")
```

it also showed me errors.